# Weird python file path behavior

Tags: python, file, operating-system

[image]

I have this folder structure, within `edi_standards.py` I want to open `csv/transaction_groups.csv`

But the code only works when I access it like this `os.path.join('standards', 'csv', 'transaction_groups.csv')`

What I think it should be is `os.path.join('csv', 'transaction_groups.csv')` since both `edi_standards.py` and `csv/` are on the same level in the same folder `standards/`

This is the output of printing `__file__` in case you doubt what I say:

```
>>> print(__file__)
~/edi_parser/standards/edi_standards.py
```

Comment: that's because you're running your code from a different directory. Try `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"csv","transaction_groups.csv")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you're running a python file, the python interpreter does not change the *current directory* to the directory of the file you're running.

In your case, you're probably running (from `~/edi_parser`):

```
standards/edi_standards.py
```

For this you have to hack something using `__file__`, taking the dirname and building the relative path of your resource file:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"csv","transaction_groups.csv")
```

Anyway, it's good practice *not* to rely on the current directory to open resource files. This method works whatever the current directory is.

Comment: Thank you that was it. Actually I didn't run it like this on purpose but it was the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with Answer of Jean-Francois above,
I would like to mention that `os.path.join` does not consider the absolute path of your current working directory as the first argument
For example consider below code

```
>>> os.path.join('Functions','hello')
'Functions/hello'
```

See another example

`>>> os.path.join('Functions','hello','/home/naseer/Python','hai')
'/home/naseer/Python/hai'`

[Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) 
states that whenever we have given a absolute path as a argument to the `os.path.join` then all previous path arguments are discarded and joining continues from the absolute path argument.

The point I would like to highlight is we shouldn't expect that the function `os.path.join` will work with relative path. So You have to submit absolute path to be able to properly locate your file.