# How to import a Python module with relative path to a file from another directory?

Tags: python

I have a Python project with subdirectories and I'm unable to import a module located in the root directory, here `logger.py`, from another module in a subdirectory, here `composite.py`.

The problem is that `logger.py` point to a log file in the `log` directory with a relative path name to it, so `composite.py` can't find this file from it's sub directory.

How can I import module `logger` from `composite.py` and from another module in the root directory, like `module.py` ?

```
├── data/
    module.py
    logger.py
    ├── composite/
    │   ├── composite.py
    ├── log/
    │   ├── info.log
```

**This work :**

data/logger.py:

```
h_info =      RotatingFileHandler('log/info.log', [...])
```

data/module.py:

```
import logger
```

**This doesn't work:**

data/composite/composite.py:

```
from data import logger

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/abc/project/python/xyz/data/composite/log/info.log'
```

Comment: have you tried `h_info =      RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'log/info.log'), [...])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get Python to import from a different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456481/cant-get-python-to-import-from-a-different-folder)

Comment: @Vil no, it's not a duplicate of this. The question is classic, but it's difficult to tag as duplicate because of the ever varying structure of the OP files

Comment: which python version you are used ?

Comment: @AmirMohsen I use Python 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because your code is relying on the current directory to open the log file.

Since you know the relative path to your log file from the file you're opening the log, you can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to locate the current directory module then join the rest:

in `logger.py`, `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is `'/home/abc/project/python/xyz/data'`. Just add the `log` folder part.

```
h_info = RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'log/info.log'), [...])
```

or in a more portable way:

```
h_info = RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"log","info.log"), [...])
```

NEVER reference resource/external files with a relative path. Always use either absolute path from a config file or use this technique to be sure of the starting directory. Never use `os.chdir` either to do this.

Similar issue: [Weird python file path behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819441/weird-python-file-)
path-behavior

Interesting related read: [os.getcwd() vs os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274040/os-getcwd-vs-os-path-abspathos-path-dirname-file)

Comment: Thank you, it works very well but I need to join `log/info.log` instead of `../log/info.log` to the module path, like in `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'log/info.log')`

Comment: Well, I learned something new here too. I usually use `os.getcwd()`. Here's a brief on which is better to be used. [os.getcwd() vs os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274040/os-getcwd-vs-os-path-abspathos-path-dirname-file)